# Tag Generating Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parsing, text, tags

I'm trying to think of an algorithm that can search through a piece of text looking for keywords for example i have an array of words:

```
Sample=['Andy' 'Murray' 'is' 'expecting' 'a' 'difficult' 'test' 'when' 'he' 'faces' 'David' 'Ferrer' 'in' 'the' 'final' 'of' 'the' 'Sony' 'Open' 'on' 'Sunday'];
```

I want to pick out the important words like "Andy, Murray, David, Ferrer, Sunday, Open, Final" etc but my knowledge of the technical side of english is limited so i dont know the types of words I should be ignoring.

are there any other good methods of finding tags from text you can suggest? /do you know the types of words i should be ignoring etc

p.s i would prefer any code to be in c++ but thats not a requirement :)

Comment: Have you written any code yet or are you just looking for an algorithm? What o you mean by tags? Like twitter?

Comment: by tags i just mean keywords, important words like the ones i suggested. But i basically just need to lose words like "is", "and" etc i just want to know if there's any pre built algorithms to handle this for me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is a bad fit for the site. Questions here should be *specific technical questions* about *actual code*. This question is vague and not really on topic and is likely to be closed.

Comment: Well if you have a list of words to exclude then its pretty easy

Comment: That said, the question you pose is an actively researched question so you should start by looking for papers on *probabalistic latent semantic analysis*. The wikipedia page has a good introduction. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLSA

Answer (score 3):

The classic way in the field of [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) to do so is using the [tf-idf model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

- The tf component indicate how much times each term repeats in the
  document/sentence - the more the 'better' - since it indicates importance in the text.
- The idf component indicates how many documents in the collection have this term in them, the lower this number is - the more significant the word is (because if a rare word appears in a text, it helps you to use this word to split this document from the others much better, for intuition - the word 'the' will most likely say nothing about the document, and the idf value makes sure its weight is small).